# Is there a way to implement this tkinter code snippet using place() method instead of pack()?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The problem: I want to use the place method, since it allows
me to place content in the window using relx/rely attributes. Since I'm using tk.Frame here, I can't use the place method (or at least I'm not aware that you can). Is there another way to do this? I want to use the place method because it's easier to place content that way for me. Code is below:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        
        weightList = ["kilogram", "pound", "ounze"]
        distanceList = ["kilometers", "meters", "miles", "yards"]
        temperatureList = ["celsius", "fahrenheit", "kelvin"]
    
    
        self.dict = {'weight': weightList,
                     'distance': distanceList,
                     'temperature': temperatureList}
       
        
        self.variable_a = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_b = tk.StringVar(self)
    
        self.variable_a.trace('w', self.update_options)
    
        self.optionmenu_a = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_a, *self.dict.keys())
        self.optionmenu_b = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_b, '')
    
        self.variable_a.set('weight')
        
        
        self.optionmenu_a.pack()
        self.optionmenu_b.pack()
        self.pack()
        
        
       
    
    def update_options(self, *args):
        Units = self.dict[self.variable_a.get()]
        self.variable_b.set(Units[0])
    
        menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
    
        for i in Units:
            menu.add_command(label=i, command=lambda current=i: self.variable_b.set(current))

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Unit Converter")
win.geometry("500x300")
win = App(win)
win.mainloop()
```

If I replace pack with place, the dropdown widgets won't appear:

```
import tkinter as tk



class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        
        weightList = ["kilogram", "pound", "ounze"]
        distanceList = ["kilometers", "meters", "miles", "yards"]
        temperatureList = ["celsius", "fahrenheit", "kelvin"]


        self.dict = {'weight': weightList,
                     'distance': distanceList,
                     'temperature': temperatureList}
       
        
        self.variable_a = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_b = tk.StringVar(self)

        self.variable_a.trace('w', self.update_options)

        self.optionmenu_a = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_a, *self.dict.keys())
        self.optionmenu_b = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.variable_b, '')

        self.variable_a.set('weight')
        
        
        self.optionmenu_a.place(relx = 0.35, rely = 0.1)
        self.optionmenu_b.place(relx = 0.75, rely = 0.1)
        self.pack()
        
        
       

    def update_options(self, *args):
        Units = self.dict[self.variable_a.get()]
        self.variable_b.set(Units[0])

        menu = self.optionmenu_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')

        for i in Units:
            menu.add_command(label=i, command=lambda current=i: self.variable_b.set(current))



win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Unit Converter")
win.geometry("500x300")
win = App(win)
win.mainloop()
```

I tried using the place method by itself, which didn't work (place instead of pack, with relx/rely attributes only).
I tried looking up a solution with tk.Frame, but I didn't understand how to do it (didn't get how I would specify width/height for both). Other than that, I also am having problems understanding how tk.Frame interacts with my code (new to tkinter).

Comment: I don't see any calls to `place` in the code you provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: there isn't any. I want to do this, but it gives an error. The code given works, but I want to replace pack() with place()

Comment: Then you should post the code using `place()` and state what is wrong and post the error if any.

Comment: ill do this now, but there specifically is no error (what happens is the window is shown empty). I'll elaborate with an edit

Comment: It is because the frame (instance of `App`) has size 1x1.  Try changing `self.pack()` to `self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)` to expand the frame to fill the window.

Answer (score 0):

> If I replace pack with place, the dropdown widgets won't appear:

This is because the use of `place` doesn't force the containing widget to resize so that it is big enough to fit all of its children. Since you don't give the initial frame a size, and because you don't force it to fill its own container, the size of the frame defaults to 1x1. It is there, but almost invisible.

A simple solution specific to this example is to force the frame to fill the space allocated to it:

```
self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you don't want it to fill the whole space, you need to tell tkinter how big to make the frame:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=300,  height=200)
        #                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ...
```

This is one of the reasons why `place` is best used only rarely. Tkinter is very good at managing the size of widgets. If you use `place`, the size and position is entirely up to you, and it becomes much more difficult to make responsive user interfaces (ones that work on a variety of resolutions, with different fonts, and behave properly when the window is resized).